# behavior of scala.Int.unbox(null)

Tags: scala

When I call `scala.Int.unbox(null)` , the result is 0

The implemention of `scala.Int.unbox` is:

```
def unbox(x: java.lang.Object): Int = x.asInstanceOf[java.lang.Integer].intValue()
```

But when I directly call `null.asInstanceOf[java.lang.Integer].intValue()`, NullPointerException is thrown, should I have missed something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where did you find that definition?  I see the [Scaladoc](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/library/scala/runtime/BoxesRunTime.java#L101) pointing to this method which explicitly specifies 0 on null input

https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/library/scala/runtime/BoxesRunTime.java#L101

Defined as:

```
public static int unboxToInt(Object i) {
    return i == null ? 0 : ((java.lang.Integer)i).intValue();
}
```

Comment: I found it in the scala.Int class, I worked in IDEA, and IDEA navigates me to the scaa.Int.unbox implementation when I click on the unbox.

Comment: I set a break point in the unboxToInt method, and it indeed run into the method unboxToInt.I wonder, its internal working when I call scala.Int.unbox, and the code path runs into BoxesRuntime#unboxToInt.

Comment: Is this an acceptable answer to your question?  As for the code path, have you tried looking through the stack frames one by one when you hit that breakpoint to see the path taken to the method?

Comment: There are no stack frames between these two method call.